# How to select a pattern which may contain the same pattern inside?

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to be able to select, for example, some text, which is between brackets.

Let's say, we have following text

```
This is a (sample (or, may be, not))  text, which I write in a browser(with keyboard)
```

What regex pattern should I use, which would select

```
(sample (or, may be, not))
```

and

```
(with keyboard)
```

for any number of nested brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the known limitations of regex is that regex can't handle nesting.  so for instance

a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> can't be matched with regex.

Properly parenthesized strings can't be matched with regex either.

Normally you would some sort of recursive Context-free Grammar implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<Depth>\()
(
(?(Depth)([^\(\)]+))
|
(?<Depth>\()
|
(?<-Depth>\))
)*
(?(Depth)(?!))
```

Works fine for me.